# How to join points by line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am using chartkick and gem "groupdate" in my project.

```
<%= area_chart SugarLevel.group_by_minute(created_at).sum(:mmol) %>
```

I want to keep continuing line from one point to another. I do something wrong with groupdate. If there is no data at some minute, the line has to start from previous point and has to finish at next point. [image]

It has to be graph without gaps. Like that:
[image]

Comment: Where did you get the second image, maybe its a different graph name.

Comment: I got this image from paint. It is example how it should look like.

Comment: no, i have not seen such examples on their site. Yes, i am open to other chart gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method in gem "groupdate" `group_by_something` uses `Hash` to store a data. For example:

```
 @hash = SugarLevel.group_by_minute(:created_at).sum(:mmol) # => {Thu, 01 Jun 2017 17:39:00 UTC +00:00=>#<BigDecimal:2add9a8,'0.77E1',18(18)>, Thu, 01 Jun 2017 17:40:00 UTC +00:00=>0, Thu, 01 Jun 2017 17:41:00 UTC +00:00=>0, Thu, 01 Jun 2017 17:42:00 UTC +00:00=>0, Thu, 01 Jun 2017 17:43:00 UTC +00:00=>0}
```

We can clear this hash as we want:

```
@hash.select{|k, v| v != 0} # Select all keys which do not consist 0
```

And eventually, we can put itin a view: `<%= area_chart @hash %>`